# What H.264 encoding profile is considered "safe" in 2017?

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264, video-encoding

Have streaming services adopted a certain H.264 profile as "standard" or "safe" for use in 2017? For example are all modern Youtube videos at least "High" profile for H.264?

Or does Youtube continue to serve all encoding profiles, down to "Baseline" depending on hardware?

I would like to start encoding my videos with "High" profile or higher, but cannot find any recent documentation on which profile is standard practice or safe to use.

**Searching google is not fruitful:**

Old blog post from 2008:
http://blog.mediacoderhq.com/h264-profiles-and-levels/

Old blog post from 2014:
http://leightronix.com/blog/when-to-choose-high-main-and-baseline-while-encoding-h-264/

**I cannot find any updated 2017 information on this.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe YouTube is choosing the H.264 profile depending on your video's resolution. I downloaded a 1080p video from my YouTube video manager and analysed the video using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/). It showed high profile with level 3.1. A 480p video showed baseline profile with level 3.

Comment: Thanks for doing the dirty work of checking some files. I wonder if anyone in the business of encoding video could chime in with some industry knowledge. I'll leave the question unanswered for now.